# Cannot upload any folders to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, upload

I'm trying to upload a folder to Google Drive (running Ubuntu 20.04).

I select New > Folder Upload and select the folder. The upload immediately fails with the error `file not found`:

[image]

It's strange that it's mentioning a "File" at all when I am specifically uploading a folder. It doesn't seem to be recognizing the folder as a folder. And it doesn't matter which folder I choose, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a bug in opera](https://forums.opera.com/topic/60755/ubuntu-opera-96-unable-to-upload-folders-in-google-drive-one-drive/5) which currently seems unresolved (also in Win 11).

- Try to use drag-and-drop.
- Try a different browser.
- Tutorial for a github project to [install drive on Ubuntu](https://techviewleo.com/mount-google-drive-on-ubuntu-debian-and-upload-files/)
- There's also a [command line tool for Linux](https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-upload-file-to-google-drive-from-linux-command-line-69668fbe4937) you can try to use.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things you can try doing:

1. Compress your folder (into a .zip or .rar) and try reuploading.
2. 'File not found' errors are usually caused by permission related errors. Go through your system/browser permissions and ensure that access to file systems is allowed.
3. Try relocating/moving your folder to another location (ideally desktop/documents/downloads) and upload it from there.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is not a permissions issue because I am able to upload files from the same directory (just the Downloads folder). So yes, I am able to upload a zip of the folder (because it's a file not a folder). But actually it seems I can't upload any folders at all, even from other directories. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

I will hazard a guess:

The snap-ed (containerized) version of your browser is unable to read the directory you are trying to upload. To make it work, you will have do move your files somewhere under /home/mysuser or /media.

Check out this for reference:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033344/how-to-give-snaps-access-to-somedir

Comment: Or you can use a browser that's not jailed / containerized. IMHO Opera is easy to install and use.

Comment: I am using Opera already. And it seems that I can't upload folder from any location, but I can upload files from any location.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the supported web browsers. From [System requirements and browsers](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375082?hl=en)

The below quote only includes text; to look for the linked resources, go to the above link.

> ##### Browsers
>
> Google Drive, Docs, Sheets, Slides, and Forms work with the 2 most recent versions of the following browsers (unless specified otherwise). Make sure cookies and JavaScript are turned on for your browser.
>
> - Chrome
> - Firefox
> - **Windows only:** Microsoft Edge
> - **Mac only:** Safari
>   Other browsers may work, but you might not be able to use all of the features.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried on the online version to upload ?
Also, Google Drive provide you two way to initiate your Drive space on your computer *disk* or *folder* in your Drive parameters : try the one you didn't.
For my part, create a virtual volume save me from this problem.
[image: LECTEUR G OU FICHIER]

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am using the online version to upload. I'm not even sure if there is a Drive app for Ubuntu.